# Create a model field that is stored in a linked object

Tags: django, django-forms

Let's suppose that I have a `Subquestion` model that links to a `Question` model with a field such as 'is_active'. Now suppose that I want the `Subquestion` to have an `is_active` field too that takes it's value from the `Question.is_active` field. To a consumer of `Subquestion`, I want it to appear as though `is_active` is actually part of the `Subquestion` class, despite being stored in the `Question` database table. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not clear with this statement **Subquestion model that links to a Question model with a field such as 'is_active'** Isn't it a foreign key relation?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class SubQuestion(models.Model):
     question = models.ForeignKey(Question, verbose_name="Main question")
     #...

     @property
     def is_active(self):
          return self.question.is_active
```

In this case, `subquestion.is_active` returns the value of `is_active` of the related question. The `property` decorator allows you to use it as an attribute of the class, without parenthesis after.

Comment: @MaximeLorant: That will appear as a normal python property, not a model field

Comment: @Casebash It is not a model field as you said, it is the field of the related object. You can still display it in the admin and use it as a regular field, but you will not be able to change it (you are force to change `self.question.is_active`, or writing a property setter). You could also make harcopy of the field if you **really** want to have a field but you need to be careful and have your tables always synced.